# JavaScript submenu doesn't work anymore after iPhone iOS 5 update

Tags: javascript, ios, ios5

I have a javascript menu that works fine on Firefox, IE, Safari and iPhone/iPad iOS 4.

Only in the iOS 5 update the submenu shows up very briefly and then disappears when a menuitems has been clicked. Does anyone know what they have changed and how I can fix this?

```
var dbMenu = {
    init: function(){
        var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');
        for(var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++){
            if(uls[i].className.search(/\bdbMenu\b/) == -1)
                continue;
            var menu = uls[i];

            dbMenu.styleSubMenus(menu);

            addEvent(menu, 'mouseover', dbMenu.hover, false);
            addEvent(menu, 'mouseout', dbMenu.hoverOff, false);
            if(menu.className.search(/\bonMouse\b/) == -1){
                addEvent(menu, 'click', dbMenu.click, false);
            }
            addEvent(menu, 'click', dbMenu.nav, false);
        }    
    },

    hover: function(e){
        var target = (window.event)? window.event.srcElement : (e)? e.target : null;

        if(target){
            target = dbMenu.getTarget(target, 'li');
            if(!target) return;
        }else{
            return;
        }

        target.className += ' hover';

        var t = (target.className.search(/\bsubMenu\b/) != -1)? target : (target.parentSubMenu)? target.parentSubMenu : null;
        if(!t) return;
        clearTimeout(t.timeout);

        if(target.parentMenu.className.search(/\bonMouse\b/) != -1){
            t.className += ' click';
        }
    },

    hoverOff: function(e){
        var target = (window.event)? window.event.srcElement : (e)? e.target : null;

        if(target){
            target = dbMenu.getTarget(target, 'li');
            if(!target) return;
        }else{
            return;
        }

        target.className = target.className.replace(/hover/g, '');

        if(target.parentMenu.className.search(/\bonMouse\b/) != -1){
            var t = (target.className.search(/\bsubMenu\b/) != -1)? target : (target.parentSubMenu)? target.parentSubMenu: null;
            if(!t) return; 
            t.timeout = setTimeout(function(){ t.className = t.className.replace(/click/g, ''); }, 80);
        }
    },

    click: function(e){
        if(window.event){
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        if(e && e.stopPropagation){
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        var target = (window.event)? window.event.srcElement : (e)? e.target : null;

        if(target){
            target = dbMenu.getTarget(target, 'li');
            if(!target) return;
        }else{
            return;
        }

        if(target.className.search(/\bclick\b/) == -1){
            target.className += ' click';
        }else{
            target.className = target.className.replace(/click/g, '');
        }
    },

    nav: function(e){
        if(window.event){
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        if(e && e.stopPropagation){
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        var target = (window.event)? window.event.srcElement : (e)? e.target : null;

        if(target){
            target = dbMenu.getTarget(target, 'li');
            if(!target) return;
        }else{
            return;
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < target.childNodes.length; i++){
            var node = target.childNodes[i];
            if(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a'){
                window.location = node.href;
                break;
            }
        }
    },

    getTarget: function(target, elm){
        if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != elm && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'body'){
            return dbMenu.getTarget(target.parentNode, elm);
        }else if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'body'){
            return null;
        }else{
            return target;
        }
    },

    styleSubMenus: function(menu){
        lis = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
            node = lis[i];
            node.parentMenu = menu;
            if(node.getElementsByTagName('ul').length != 0){
                node.className += ' subMenu';
                sublis = node.getElementsByTagName('li');
                for(var j = 0; j < sublis.length; j++){
                    sublis[j].parentSubMenu = node;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture){  //cross-browser event handling for IE5+, NS6+, and Mozilla/Gecko By Scott Andrew
    if(elm.addEventListener){
        elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
        return true;
    }else if(elm.attachEvent){
        var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
        return r;
    }else{
        elm['on' + evType] = fn;
    }
}

addEvent(window, 'load', dbMenu.init, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first, and most important, thing is that touch devices don't have click events. Mobile Safari emulates click, mouseover and mouseout events. Apple may have changed how it determines what a click is in iOS 5.

Check to make sure the events aren't being captured by your hover handlers. I would start by enabling the [developer console on your iOS device](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/14447/step-by-step-turn-on-the-iphone-ipads-web-debugging-console/) and add logging to each of the events. This should tell you what events are being fired and when they are being fired.

To fix it you may want to check if the device supports touch events. Something like `"ontouchstart" in window` should do the trick and only bind the event (hover or click) that is necessary for that device.